# Can i broadcast from Angular2 to a JavaScript listener

Tags: angular, events, gwt

I have an application where the front-end is written using two technologies. Old front-end was written on GWT and new on Angular 2. And now they coexist together until we rewrite everything to Angular.
But sometimes we need to say something from GWT to Angular. Or in another way. For example, we have an old modal window that written on GWT. And we need open it from Angular. 
For this we make NgFacade on GWT, that can push and subscribe to the event using window variable and native js:

```
private static native void pushEvent(String ngEventId)/*-{
  if($wnd.ngGwtEventBus){
     $wnd.ngGwtEventBus.pushEvent(ngEventId)
  }
}-*/

private static native void subscribeEvent(String ngEventId, Comand comand)/*-{
  if($wnd.ngGwtEventBus){
     $wnd.ngGwtEventBus.subscribeEvent(ngEventId, there comand that we want execute)
  }
}-*/
```

And on the Angular side, we create eventBus service where we push event and this service can emit it like there:

```
private emitters: {[eventId:string]:EventEmmiter<any>}= {};

private getEmitter(eventId:string):EventEmmiter<any> {
   if (!this.emmiters[eventId]){
      this.emmiters[eventId] = new EventEmmiter();
   }
   return this.emmiters[eventId]
}

public pushEvent(event: AppEvent<any>):void {
  this.getEmitter(event.getId).emmit(event.getValue);
}
```

Before everything works well. On app init we create an event handler on GWT side write it on window variable. And then we need only init event from this singleton service from the Angular side.

But after we refactored Angular side of the app and divided everything on the different modules that load using `LazyLoading`. We move this service to `SharedModule` and it stops work. I use `forRoot` section for this and import `SharedModule` in `AppModule` using `SharedModule.forRoot()`.

Yes, I still can emit event from service if get a native `window` object and emit event directly by reference to it. But before I can Emmti event in this service and handler in my Window know about this event. Look like I can emit event everywhere. Somebody can help me.

Maybe somebody knows how emit event from angular to `JavaScript/Jquery` listener that init outside the angular app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript events, after all both languages are javascript at runtime and it's convenient to leverage the browser event mechanism.

Here an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events